# Creating another column using values of rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns in a table

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | one |
| First | 2 | two |
| First | 3 | three |
| First | 4 | four |
| First | 5 | five |
| Second | 2 | two_second |

And so on...
I want to group by first column and create a second column which is a map based on some condition, eg. if Col2 >=3
So, map would look like
{3 : three, 4: four, 5:five}
And the final output would be

| Col1 | Output Column |
| --- | --- |
| First | {3: three, 4: four, 5: five} |
| Second | {4: four_second} |

And so on.
Can we do something like this in presto?

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: *if Col2 >=3 So, map would look like {3 : three, 4: four , 5:five}* There is no `3 : three` in source data - where it is taken from?

Comment: Looks like you want `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Col1, JSON_OBJECTAGG(Col2, Col3)
FROM test
WHERE Col2 >=3
GROUP BY Col1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc58bf34b42618173ee5917db75f1013

Map it to Presto by yourself. Or use raw SQL.